# Method to check Login Details against SQLite database in Android Application not working

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

relatively new to android development. I am creating an Android Studio Application that allows a user to login to a system by checking the existing email address and password provided against a table created using SQLite. When the user provides an existing email and password an activity starts an intent to change the layout to the home screen. If incorrect an unsuccessful Login attempt Toast message appears.

The database has been created successfully, however the user is automatically signed in regardless of whether the email address or password they provide is correct OR NOT. I am not sure if the rawQuery I am using in the hasObject method is correct.

I have included the RegistrationDatabaseHelper.java class below, with the hasObject method being the final method:

```
public class RegistrationDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//declaring variable so we can find the name of our database
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "belfast.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "reg_details_table";
public static final String COL_1 ="ID";
public static final String COL_2 ="EMAIL";
public static final String COL_3 ="USERNAME";
public static final String COL_4 ="PASSWORD";
public static final String COL_5 ="DOB";
public static final String COL_6 ="MOBILE";

//default constructor below
public RegistrationDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    //when the constructor is called it will create your database
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //creating the table WITHIN the database below
    db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,EMAIL TEXT,USERNAME TEXT,PASSWORD STRING,DOB TEXT,MOBILE LONG) ");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

//creating a method below to insert data
public boolean insertData(String emailAddress, String userName, String password, String dob, Long mobileNumber){
    //we will use this SQLDatabase instance to insert our data
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //now we need to create an instance of the class ContentValue
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    //we will now take this contentValues instance and insert it into the data columns
    //the first arg is the column name itself, the second is the data itself.
    contentValues.put(COL_2, emailAddress);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, userName);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, password);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, dob);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, mobileNumber);
    //we then insert our data using the db instance created above
    //this takes three arguments. The first is the table name, The second is null and the third
    //is the contentValues which we have created.
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if (result==-1){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//creating a method that will show all data that has been entered into the database, using
//elements from the Cursor class. The Cursor interface allows read-write access to the result
public Cursor getAllData(){
    //creating an instance of the database class firstly to allow us to get all the data
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //now we will create an instance of the Cursor class called result and use the
    //rawQuery method. Basically creates a SQL query.
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ TABLE_NAME,null);
    //we will now return the instance of this cursor, which is "result"
    return result;

}
//creating a method that will update all data in our database, using 4 args all of which are
//string, they are id, name, surname and marks
public boolean updateData(String emailAddress, String userName, String password, String dob, Long mobileNumber){
    //creating an instance of the database class firstly to allow us to get all the data
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //now we need to create an instance of the class ContentValue
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    //we will now take this contentValues instance and insert it into the data columns
    //the first arg is the column name itself, the second is the data itself.
    contentValues.put(COL_2, emailAddress);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, userName);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, password);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, dob);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, mobileNumber);
    //the below update method will update any args you pass through here
    //the first argument is the table name itself, the second is the contentValues, the third
    //is the condition you want to impose, such as "ID = ?" where the ? is the ID provided. The
    //fourth arg is the String[] array
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "EMAIL = ?", new String[] {emailAddress});
    //we will return true to see if the data is really updated or not
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteData(String emailAddress){
    //creating an instance of the database class firstly to allow us to get all the data
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //calling the delete function on our db instance. It takes 3 args, 1st is the name of the
    //table, the second is the ID number represented by "ID = ?" and the third arg is the String
    //Array[] of the argument type id. The return below returns the integer of the ID
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "EMAIL = ?", new String[] {emailAddress});

}

public boolean hasObject(String emai){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + "= ?";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectString,null);
    boolean exist;
    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        exist=true;
    } else {
        exist=false;
    }
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    return exist;
}
}
```

The SignInActivity.java class is listed below also, with the signIn method determining if the user successfully logins or not:

```
public class SignInActivity extends Activity {

//creating an instance of the RegistrationDatabaseHelper class
RegistrationDatabaseHelper myDb;

EditText userName;
EditText password;
Button emailSignIn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_screen);

    myDb = new RegistrationDatabaseHelper(this);

    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);

    emailSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);

    signIn();


}

public void signIn(){
    emailSignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean recordExists = myDb.hasObject(userName.getText().toString());
            if(recordExists=true){
                Intent intentSignIn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePageActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successful, redirecting to Home Page.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(intentSignIn);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid credentials, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}    
}
```

Does anyone know why the user is logged in regardless of the input? As I said I'm relatively new to android development and am not sure where I am going wrong, so any advice at all would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, should the parameter **email** be added to the rawQuery instead of **null**? Apologies I'm still unsure as to how the rawQuery should be correctly written :(

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`I am not sure if the rawQuery I am using in the hasObject method is correct.` No, it's **not**:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectString,null);
```

You're not passing the parameter (`?`) you intended to use in your `WHERE` clause.
Instead, you're passing **null**.

Correct implementation:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectString, new String[]{"Your search string here"});
```

Don't worry about the single quotes (SQL string delimiters): they'll be added automatically as needed.

Comment: Thanks Rotwang, I've updated the rawQuery to include the correct paramters (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectString, new String[]{email});)

Comment: And now it magically works. Don't forget to accept my answer (I guess you'll have to wait for a couple of days before being able to tick the checkmark), so to remove your post from the Unanswered Questions Queue.

Comment: However it still logs in any username or email, regardless of whether it its on the SQLite databsae or not, I think I have a problem with the signIn method in my SignInActivity class

Comment: I can't see the checkmark yet but once I do I'll make sure to do so!

Comment: `I think I have a problem with the signIn method in my SignInActivity class` You possibly have the very same issue. This time you'll want to pass **2** parameters, as in `db.rawQuery(selectString, new String[]{userID, userPWD});)`

Comment: Hmmm, I've updated the code to:                                                                      'public boolean hasObject(String email, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + "= ?" + " AND "+ COL_4 + " =?";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectString, new String[]{email, password});'                                                                                                  but I'm still getting the same error, I think I will have to go back through my code

Comment: Check if the data has been inserted in a wrong way (i.e.: with trailing blank spaces). "password " won't match " password".